# multiple DNS services

Tags: systemd, dnsmasq, avahi

On my *Fedora* system : a simple PC workstation behind a provider box with an extra laptop also on *Fedora*, I have **dnsmasq**, **avahi-daemon** and **systemd-resolved** which all manage DNS connections.

avahi-daemon :

> The Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD daemon implements Apple's Zeroconf architecture
> (also known as "Rendezvous" or "Bonjour"). The daemon registers local
> IP addresses and static services using mDNS/DNS-SD and provides two
> IPC APIs for local programs to make use of the mDNS record cache the
> avahi-daemon maintains.

dnsmasq :

> dnsmasq is a lightweight DNS, TFTP, PXE, router advertisement and DHCP
> server. It is intended to provide coupled DNS and DHCP service to a
> LAN.

systemd-resolver :

> systemd-resolved is a system service that provides network name
> resolution to local applications. It implements a caching and
> validating DNS/DNSSEC stub resolver, as well as an LLMNR and
> MulticastDNS resolver and responder.

My question is : isn't this overkill ? Or do I miss something ? I don't really get the fundamental differences between them.
And if I need just one, which one would that be ?

Thanks